# Resize AWS instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Rails application hosted on aws where two instances are being used.

```
 1. db instance - m3.medium
 2. app instance - c4.xlarge
```

I want to resize both these instances in a safe manner(not losing any data and should be able to revert in case of failure).
Can someone help me here please?

Comment: Are you using the instance store on the m3.medium instance?

Comment: How can I check that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can resize an Amazon EC2 instance with these steps:

1. Stop the instance
2. Change the Instance Type (Actions / Instance Settings / Change Instance Type)
3. Start the instance

Stopping and Starting will *not* lose any data (except for data stored on [Instance Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html). You can also repeat the above steps to revert back to the prior Instance Type.

**How to detect Instance Store**

Firstly, check your [instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). The M3 family supports instance store, but the C4 family does not.

Then, look at the disks on your system. Instance Store appears as `emphemeral`:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.9G   60K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  976M  6.7G  13% /
/dev/xvdb       3.9G  8.1M  3.7G   1% /media/ephemeral0
```

Under Windows, Instance Store will appear as X/Y/Z drives.

Comment: How do I figure out whether I am using instance store or EBS?

Comment: Added info to answer.

Comment: I logged into both the systems and didn't find ephemeral in either. FWIW I also checked EBS volumes and found two entries for the two instances.
Does this mean I have EBS backed instances ?

Comment: These days, you would *always* have EBS-backed instances. Some instance types, however, allow you to *additionally* have Instance Store volumes, which are great for swap-files and temporary files.